# Concatenating specific rows from a sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix (using scipy.sparse) with I rows and U columns, U is much greater than I.
I have a list of U random numbers in the range of 0:I.
I would like to create a new sparse matrix which will be a U * U sparse matrix, the row for user u will hold all the U values in row i of the original sparse matrix.
For example, if the original matrix is a 3*5 matrix:

```
0,0,2,1,0
0,0,3,4,1
1,1,0,2,0
```

and the list of random numbers is [0,0,2,1,2]

The resulting matrix should be:

```
0,0,2,1,0
0,0,2,1,0
1,1,0,2,0
0,0,3,4,1
1,1,0,2,0
```

I am using this code now, which is very very slow:

```
for u in range(U):
    i= random_indices[u]
    if u == 0:
        output_sparse_matrix = original_sparse_matrix[i, :]
    else:
        output_sparse_matrix = vstack((output_sparse_matrix,
                                       original_sparse_matrix[i, :]))
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done quicker?

**Update**
I used Jérôme Richard's suggestion, but inside a loop - since I got an out of memory error. This is the solution that worked:

```
bins = np.array_split(random_indices, 10)
output_sparse_matrix = original_sparse_matrix[bins[0]]

for bin in bins[1:10]:
   output_sparse_matrix = vstack((output_sparse_matrix ,original_sparse_matrix[bin]))
```

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?  or `scipy.sparse`?

Comment: I'm using scipy.sparse

Comment: Even with dense arrays, repeatedly doing concatenate in a loop is slow.  There we recommend collecting the arrays in a list and doing one join at the end.  I haven't played with `sparse.vstack` much, but I think the same applies  `sparse.vstack` combines the `coo` attributes of its arguments, and uses them to make a new `coo` matrix.

Comment: Look at the code for `sparse.vstack`.  It delegates the task to `sparse.bmat`, `bmat([[b] for b in blocks])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vstack` create a new matrix for every iteration. This is the main source of slowdown since the complexity of the algorithm is `O(U^3)`. You can just append the new lines in a Python list and then `vstack` the list of lines. Alternatively, a better approach is just to use the following Numpy expression :

`original_sparse_matrix[random_indices, :]`

Comment: I am getting an error: ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed, although none of the random indices is negative (all are between 0 and 999).

Comment: I the error coming from this line or what you do with the result? Even negative indices are permitted here. The only possible failures are an explicit out-of-range error or a an out-of-memory one.

Comment: Yes - this line. It was probably out of memory

Answer (score 1):

This may no be faster but you can try using fancy indexing:

```
output_sparse_matrix = input_sparse_matrix[random_indices]
```

provided random_indices is a list the above should give the desired result.

Applying this to your original example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

a = csr_matrix([[0,0,2,1,0],
[0,0,3,4,1],
[1,1,0,2,0]])

indices =  [0,0,2,1,2]


output_matrix = a[indices]

print(output_matrix.todense())
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed, although none of the random indices is negative (all are between 0 and 999)